# Can i use socket as a client and a server at the same time

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I have this school assignment, where i need to develop a program that basically creates a node in a tree, that communicates via  TCP between node, and i have a question, can i use a single TCP socket to connect as client and as a server to different devices, since i want to make it that the connection to the node above (parent) was a client in child and server in the parent. But then the same node can be child and parent at the same to different nodes, so the relationship would rotate and the socket would handle it. Is this possible, if so how?

Answer (score 1):

No, with TCP that isn't possible.  A TCP sockets represent one endpoint of a one-to-one connection (analogous to a telephone call), so it can only be used to communicate with that one remote program at the other end of the connection.  If you want to communicate with multiple destinations, then you need to create and use multiple TCP sockets (one for each destination).

(If you were using UDP, that would be different; a single UDP socket can be used to communicate with multiple parties, since with UDP you can explicitly specify a separate destination for each packet you send)

Comment: So, how could i do this? I need to use tcp for this, without having to create an absurd amount of sockets in each node. And another question, can i have multiple sockets in the same port?

Comment: Do the same things you would do to create and set up a single socket, but multiple times, and keep all the file descriptors in a list or data structure of some sore.  Then you can use `select()` or `poll()` or some other I/O-multiplexing function to determine which socket(s) are currently ready-for-read/ready-for-write, and handle each socket's needs as they occur.